# Should I stub hidden dependencies in Python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection, dependency-management

Python is very specific language which gives developer huge flexibility.

So if I have class like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, engine: Engine):
        self._engine = engine  # dependency injection
        self.speed = 0

    def accelerate(self, target_speed: int):
        if self._engine.can_accelerate_to_speed(target_speed):
            self.speed = target_speed
```

testing it is a piece of cake.

```
def test_car_acceleration():
    car = Car(engine=MagicMock())
    car.accelerate(100)
    assert car.speed == 100
```

But what if the `engine` dependency is hidden?

```
class SlowCar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = DefaultEngine()  # hidden dependency or maybe implementation detail?
        self.speed = 0

    def accelerate(self, target_speed: int):
        if self.engine.can_accelerate_to_speed(target_speed):
            self.speed = target_speed
```

What is the right approach for the `SlowCar`? Let's assume `SlowCar` is intended to have `DefaultEngine` mounted by default, but nothing prevents class consumer from doing so:

```
car = SlowCar()
car.engine = HEMI()
```

Anyway should I treat `SlowCar.engine` as dependency or implementation detail?
Should I `patch` it out?

```
def test_slow_car():
    with patch('path.to.SlowCar.DefaultEngine'):
        car = SlowCar()
        car.accelerate(100)
    assert car.speed == 100

def test_slow_car_way2():
    car = SlowCar()
    car.engine = MagicMock()
    car.accelerate(100)
    assert car.speed == 100
```

I guess that while `SlowCar.engine` is "public" field I may consider patching it as it's part of public API so it seems to be clearly a dependency.

But if I would have `SlowCar._engine`.. A "private" field is not part of public API so it seems more like implementation detail and it should not be mocked/patched. That's internal part of `SlowCar` which I as a consumer should not care about, right? It's tightly coupled to `SlowCar` and `SlowCar` does work with it or does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Is `DefaultEngine` deterministic and side effect free? Will it always be?

Many things can be considered a unit for a unit test but if you can’t predict what the unit will do it’s a poor unit.

That said, a unit can be far more than a single class. We’re testing an abstraction not how it works.

Now if `DefaultEngine` simply must be mocked... well it’s nicer if it’s the default value of an optional parameter  then a hidden dependency anyway.

Now sure, it’s Python. So you can sneak around the back. But now you’re testing the back. It’s better to stick to the front. Because that way the front is the only thing that you have to be consistent about.